# Resource limits have been exceeded. Data collection in this window has been stopped. Visual Studio 2017

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2017, diagnostic-tools, debug-diagnostic-tool

I am running an ASP.NET MVC web application on Visual Studio 2017 over IIS.

The Diagnostic Tools tell me the alert:

> Resource limits have been exceeded. Data collection in this window has
>   been stopped.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

It happens after running around 5 mins. I stopped and restarted it, still the same thing.

Checked the computer memory in the task manager. There is still some space.

What causes this?

Comment: Could you please tell me which version of the VS 2017 you have used? 15.2? According to this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55968/vs-2017-diagnostic-tools-draining-memory.html), I suggest you could update your VS version to 15.3 or later.

Comment: @BrandoZhang The version of VS 2017 is 15.8.8 The alert shows after a few mins in debugging session and it does not end.

Comment: I suggest you could also create a problem in this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to ask VS product group for help. This issue is resolved by 15.3.

Comment: Did you try playing around with the Diagnostics settings?

Answer (score 24):

The default value of the diagnostic settings timeout is 5 minutes, that's why.

You can change it like this:

[image: Step1]

[image]

[image]

It's confusing at first if you don't read everything because it says "Minimum session duration" but whatever. **Keep in mind you'll have to restart the debugging session (unfortunately)**.

You can also disable the resource usage limits altogether and that will work too. Good luck =)